# Gaussian process regression, multiple optima on marginal likelihood

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, gaussian-process

I have performed Gaussian process regression on a data set $D$. The marginal likelihood function that can be seen in the contour plot below (that I plot against the two hyper-parameters: $\sigma_n$ (noise standard deviation) and $l$ (characteristic length)) contains two optimum. From the graphs produced it appears (to my eye) that there is a better fit corresponding to hyper-parameters at the stationary point with the smaller marginal likelihood. 
The function generated using hyper-parameters corresponding to smaller marginal likelihood is the plot in the middle. The function generated using hyper-parameters corresponding to larger marginal likelihood is the bottom plot.

[image: Marginal Likelihood contour plot]
[image: Data generated using hyper-parameters corresponding to smaller marginal likelihood]
[image: Data generated using hyper-parameters corresponding to larger marginal likelihood]

I have read that when multiple optima occur then the posterior distribution should be looked at. Is this correct? If so could someone please shed some light on this. If not does anybody have any suggestions? 
Thank you

Comment: Extrapolation is a dangerous thing, and those 2 GP fits have very different "opinions" of the extrapolation out to 8.

Comment: This is when a prior on the hyperparameters comes in useful - the ability for the user to specify a priori what they think the the function should look like (check out MAP estimates versus MLE estimates). The predictions look very different, so any intuition you have about how you would expect the function to act is extremely valuable. **Waiting for the frequentist to down vote this comment**

Comment: Ok thanks. After having a second look it appears that the second plot perhaps is better. There may be overfitting problems with the first!